# how to export r table to pdf?

Tags: r, export-to-pdf

I have a table created in R that I would really like to download as a pdf file. When looking around I haven't managed to find any remotely easily copied solution. Is it generally just a very complicated process, or does anyone know of a good way of going about it using the below example?
Thanks!

```
library(gtsummary)
data(trial)
trial2 <- trial %>% select(trt, grade)
trial2 %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)
```

[image]

Comment: See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtsummary/vignettes/rmarkdown.html) and [here](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/gtsave.html). It does not seem like it is supported yet. You can use alternative like flex_table.

Answer (score 0):

You can export a {gtsummary} to PDF via a few different print engines. Take a look at the summary graphic below.
https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html
[image]

While gt to PDF has come far recently, there are a few formatting things that are not yet supported. My current recommendation is to use `as_kable_extra()` BUT from the dev version of gtsummary on GitHub (v1.5.2.9020): there have been recent updates that make it the best PDF option at the moment (although, I fully expect gt to soon be the best option soon).

To install the dev version from github, use `devtools::install_github("ddsjoberg/gtsummary")`. You can also use the huxtable export option to PDF as well using the version of gtsummary currently on CRAN.